# Add additional CKEDITOR languages

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need some help with a problem in CKEditor. I can't add Spanish as an additional language.

My project currently has 2 languages: `en` and `pt-br`

Today, I need to add `es` (Spanish)

As you can see in the following image, I put `es.js` with the other ones.

[image]

But when I check the available languages in the console, the Spanish option does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebuild the package that you have (you can find a link to [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) in your `build-config.js` file) with more languages. Adding files to the `lang/` directory will not be enough because CKEditor will not know about them (it's only a client-side code).

Comment: Easy and effective. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot